# misbehaving python sys script

Tags: python, linux

I made this little python script for updating(but haven't put in all the commands yet, just wanted to try one update command) my system , but it misbehaves after entering root/superuser mode.

I was wondering if anyone could point out the problem/bug.

```
import os

print "\t Entering Upgrade Mode "

if os.system("su")==1:
      print "passed"
      os.system("apt-get update")
      os.system(exit)
else:
      print "failed"
```

Comment: Perhaps you somehow caused apt-get update to invoke your script?

Comment: Is the script named `su` by any chance?

Comment: nah it's named **l_update**

Comment: Does it print `passed`?

Comment: weirdly enough, now it just enters root mode and prints neither passed nor failed

Comment: Yeah it won't do anything after that because it's switched the user to root. Try replacing `su` with `sudo echo 'Hello'` for example. Also you should probably be using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: perhaps there are certain linux commands that can't be called from a python script without errors?

Comment: @mutzmatron what would you say to this : before the looping happened tt printed `passed`..I don't think your argument stands.

Comment: @nerorevenge - Very strange - I just tested and it stays logged in to root - if I type exit it THEN prints the second statement (after "Entering upgrade mode") - so it performs as I expected. I can't comment on what you see as I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @mutzmatron wait when you enter `exit` it prints `fail` right? I am finding difficulty reproducing the main error now

Comment: Yes. It prints fail because the 'su' call returns 0. Could you edit the posting to reflect your current code?

Comment: @mutzmatron why does su call give out 0 on exit? should it be giving out a 0 iff the password is incorrect? I haven't modified my code ..it still stays the same as above.

Comment: @nerorevenge - According to the man page, su returns the exit status of the executed command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the call to `su` is the issue. The call won't exit until you exit the sub-shell (in this case logging you out of root). This means that any subsequent calls are executed as the (presumably) normal user again.

Try the following:

```
import os

print "\t Entering Upgrade Mode "

os.system("sudo apt-get update")
```

Alternatively `su` requires the `-c` flag to process the subsequent command, e.g.

```
su -c "echo Hello"
```

You should probably be using `subprocess` though; `os.system` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the fact that logging out of root unblocks the script is only incidental.  The `system` call dispatches the command to a subshell of the shell running the Python code, then blocks until that subshell returns.  The subshell running `su` doesn't return until you `exit` it, so the Python program blocks on the `system` call indefinitely.

Comment: @sr2222 - We're saying the same thing, I probably should have used more precise wording: when I said logging out of root, I was referring to logging out of the sub-shell, i.e. typing exit!

Comment: Yeah, just the way you phrased it sounded like the elevated privilege was the problem, not the still running subshell.

Comment: @sr2222 - Good call - I modified the wording; hopefully this is a little clearer now.

Comment: And if you use subprocess, you can then bind to the i/o streams and work interactively with the subshell without blocking the Python script, which might be helpful with this sort of script.